# Android App Signing, How to upload an update

Tags: android, android-app-signing

I have an application which uses app signing in Play Store, when I want to update my application, I got an error, says that

> Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your
>   App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again

, I have `keystore` file, `upload certificate` and `private_key.pepk` file. I cannot understand how to do it. Could you please explain it?

I already tried clean and rebuild project.

Comment: You should sign it with the main keystore. The one which you used to generate `private_key.pepk`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your app bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507156/your-android-app-bundle-is-signed-with-the-wrong-key-ensure-that-your-app-bundl)

Comment: @hardartcore how to do it? I didn't find any full information about this

Comment: @grrigore it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a key then the only option is to contact Google App Store support and ask to Reset the `Key`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this page: [Sign your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing) you have **App signing key** and **Upload key**. Based on your settings in Google Play Store in some cases upload key & app signing key can be the same. If you choose the option that Google should take care signing your app, those keys are not the same one.

In your case, **App signing key** is generated by Google Play Store and **Upload key** is the one which you used to sign your app and upload it for the first time in Play Store.

So in order to post an update you should use **Upload key** to sign your apk or app bundle and upload it to Play Store.

Here is a quote from documentation:

> If you choose for Google to generate the app signing key for you when you opt in, then the key you use to sign your app for release is designated as your upload key.

More information about the difference between the keys you can find in this section: [Certificates](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#certificates)

Comment: Ok but I cannot find an info, how to sign an app with these information

Comment: @enesigneci Do you know how to sign an app with keystore?

Comment: Yes, when I sign app with keystore file, it signs and I can install it on device, but when upload to Play Store, it shows an error.

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same keystore, the first one which you used to sign the app before uploading to Play Store?

Comment: Yes, I am using same keystore file that used for first release