# Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again: SHA1:

Tags: android, google-play, keystore, google-play-console, android-app-signing

I succesfully signed my android app using a keystore which i generated for my previous app. But when i am trying to upload it to play console it is showing the above error. When i sign the app with a new keystore, even in this case the play console is showing an error that the keystore differ from the previously uploaded one.

For your information, The two apps are different.
Some one already asked a question just like this, But those answers did not worked for me. So please can some one help me with this??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I answered to this same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52577357/4265103 Find the keystore you used to sign the first bundle you uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was a very basic one. I had to clean my project and then rebuild it.

Android Studio was signing my app bundle with the old certificate i was using.

What I did previously is go to Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK and i changed the jks file in the file selector to the new upload jks. It seems Android Studio caches the old certificate path and uses it even though I've selected a new one. Might be a bug in AS.

So yeah ... now if I clean the project every time i change the jks file it works, the apk or app bundle gets signed with the proper certificate...

Comment: Everytime I clean, rebuild, and do a new keystore, I still get the same error, that it's look for a specific key