# How to sign App Bundle in android studio using Google App signing certificate/Upload certificate?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, google-play, google-play-console

Can someone explain to me how exactly I can sign an App bundle for a new React Native app that I will upload to the Play store? I downloaded the App signing certificate and Upload certificate, but when I upload the Appbundle.aab to the App releases in Playstore it says:

> your android app bundle is signed with the wrong key. ensure that your app bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again

How can I create the Keystore with the Upload_certificate.der and how exactly can I sign it?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507156/your-android-app-bundle-is-signed-with-the-wrong-key-ensure-that-your-app-bundl/56122639