# Expo - Android App bundle signed with wrong key

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, expo, google-play-console

I have an app that is published to the Google Play store and I recently upgraded my expo sdk version from 28 to 39. When I uploaded the App Bundle for the new release I got an error saying that the upload certificates did not match. I initially tried following this user's advice (https://stackoverflow.com/a/59517306/9053902) but had no success. I eventually submitted a request for a key reset per the google support docs (https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756#create)

After the key was reset I attempted to build and resubmit but got the same upload certificate mismatch error. So I ran "expo build:android -c". Now the error says the signing key is wrong. I have the original downloaded .jks file, keystore password, key alias, and key password so I attempted to rebuild the App Bundle by manually providing expo with the path to the .jks file but the signing error persists.

How can I view the contents of the .jks file to check the signing key values and what other steps can I take? Also, is the .pem file that I created for the key reset supposed to be used for anything?

Answer (score 0):

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756

**Request for new upload certificate**

1. Fill up this form 
   https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/key
2. Generate Signed Bundle or APK 
   [new_key].der
3. Generate .pem and Upload
   $ keytool -export -rfc -keystore [new_key].der -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem
4. Wait for Google's email reply

It takes about 2 to 3 days to update to the new keystore once google verified it.

Answer (score 0):

**--clear-cache** is a flag to clear cache before the build:

```
eas build -p android --clear-cache
eas build -p ios --clear-cache
```