# Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key google play console

Tags: android, android-studio

this is the first time I publishing an android app on google play.
I've generated aap file for my application and when I tried to upload it to google play I got this error

```
Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
SHA1: EB:7E:87:E8:83:62:EE:08:07:67:A6:5D:FA:31:C0:4B:7C:A8:46:02
but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has a fingerprint:
SHA1: 8B:75:AC:86:40:58:9E:BE:BE:9F:EC:B0:E6:CB:1C:37:3F:72:D8:DF
```

I've searched for a solution but I couldn't resolve this problem so what is this problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Probably you signed your app bundle with a key different from the one that is saved in your console.

Comment: this is the first time I tried to publish app

Comment: Have you used the same `Keystore` file which you uploaded before? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52577357/2462531

Comment: No I didn't have any keystore before this is my first time

Comment: Did you find a fix for this?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you try to sign APP with debug KEY? Just check you app sign with

```
keytool -list -v -alias key0 -keystore ~/android/Keystore/release.keystore
```

where `~/android/Keystore/release.keystore` release keystore, not

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

If you have no release keystore, create new in Android Studio
[Android Studio make a new keystore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXoM3.png)

Answer (score 2):

Make these changes in android/app/build.gradle file:

```
signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

Answer (score 0):

there is sign in option just click and upload with new keystore.jks file this work for me[image]