# SHA-1 Certificate mismatch in Google Play Console

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-play-console, sha

When i'm trying to upload AAB to google play console, it shows me this error:

> Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:
> SHA1: XXXXXX
> but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has fingerprint:
> SHA1: YYYYYY

Google Cloud Console uses YYYYYY certificate, same as in keystore, but google play console uses XXXXXX certificate and I can't change it same as keystore. Tried to create new keystore, and some other solutions i found on the internet, nothing changed.

Comment: This post can help you solve your problem. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507156/your-android-app-bundle-is-signed-with-the-wrong-key-ensure-that-your-app-bundl)

Comment: Already fixed by contacting Google play support

Comment: Hi @APTEM59
What was the exact issue, i am also facing same issue with one of my app

Comment: @Dulanga change app signing key (inside App integrity section of Google play console) to your Unity project's one.